# Using Qunit to test a returned function

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jquery-plugins, qunit

I'm currently learning unit testing and how to use QUnit and thought that the best way to do this would be using a small jQuery plugin that I've written.

Within the plugin I've extended the easing object using the equations from an easing plugin like so:

```
$.extend( $.easing, {

    'ease-in': function (x, t, b, c, d) {
      return c*(t/=d)*t*t + b;
    },
    'ease-out': function (x, t, b, c, d) {
      return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
    },
});
```

Now I try to use this within a QUnit test:

```
equal(jQuery.easing['ease-in'],
      function (x, t, b, c, d) {return c*(t/=d)*t*t + b;},
      'ease-in returns correct function');
```

and it fails... am I missing something or have I got the wrong end of the stick somewhere?

Comment: That's because a function is an object, and objects equal with reference, not value. `(function() {}) !== (function() {})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how unit testing is (usually) done -- there's no reason to test whether a method's code equals the test code (you know it does!). What unit testing is for is to make sure that the *results* are equal. How the method calculates the result is not important.

So, your test should look something like this:

```
var easeIn = jQuery.easing['ease-in'];
equal(
    easeIn( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ),
    123  // or whatever the result should be
);
```